# Store shape in database - data structure

Tags: java, android, canvas, data-structures

I need to store shapes in the database so they could be drawn on canvas. The simplest way is just to store list of points and then draw a line using some standard interpolation method. This would require a lot of points to be accurate for all possible shapes (interpolation methods would have problems with sharp edges - like rectangles). Is there a smarter way to do that? It would be ideal if I could see the shapes without drawing them  so they could be kept in resources directory as images (9 path or something)...

Comment: see VectorDrawable and the data model it uses to draw the path

Answer (score 0):

pskink's idea is pretty cool. You can choose to use VectorDrawable to store the shapes in your resource folder see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html.

Storing shapes in database sounds a little awkward. but if it works, you can as well consider using the VectorDrawable to programatically draw the shapes without the challenge of sharp edges. thanks

Comment: The problem is VectorDrawable was added in API level 21 which is quite new and not many devices have it installed. I'll look into how it's implemented

Comment: It seems nice, thank you! How can I sample svg to get XY coordinates?

Comment: xy coordinates?  means?

Comment: Points on the 2-dimensional surface - the only thing I can get from user drawing on the screen. I have either to cast SVG to the list of pixels or to let user draw SVG in order to compare those two - since the latter does not seem possible I must stick to the first idea.